# iOS enterprise app on an unsecured server?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning

So work for a university, and we have an app that we want the students to use. It's having some trouble passing the 'Design' aspect of the Apple review. We're working on revising the design aspects, but want to use our Enterprise distribution account in the meantime to release to the campus. It's not a true enterprise app, but we want to use this distribution channel since the students are on campus already. Apple docs says:

> It’s up to you to design and host the website used to distribute apps. Make sure that users are authenticated, perhaps using basic auth or directory-based authentication, and that the website is accessible via your intranet or the Internet. You can place the app and manifest in a hidden directory, or in any other location that’s readable using HTTP or HTTPS.

We want to just put this on an unsecured webpage. I'm pretty sure Apple won't mind, or even do any checks for that, but I'm wondering if anyone else has any advice or intuition for possible consequences of putting it on some unsecured web page.

thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this question go to ServerFault?

Comment: I'm mostly talking about legal consequences, not functional consequences. We can do it just fine, but we want to know if it's actually okay to do it without putting the university somewhere it shouldn't be.

Comment: the problem with this is that in this case your question is even more off topic.